# Align relative Div on bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to align my Div Element to the bottom of the page. It has a 100% width but it should have a 10px margin on each side.

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 70%;  
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    bottom: 0;

}

<div class="footer">
        <ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
```

But here you have the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/osws9p4s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed width and used left and right property with position... please check below code and link, hope it helps.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/osws9p4s/1/)

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 70%;  
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:15px;
    right:15px;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make the position absolute and it will be at the bottom

```
.footer {
position: absolute;
font-size: 70%;  
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

> Update:

https://jsfiddle.net/osws9p4s/

Comment: But then I do not have the margin on the right side :/

Comment: Change the margin as margin:15px;